# Can Proper Case be done in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typesetting, style

Can we do the **Proper Case** to our text in *Adobe Photoshop*

I am trying to create a flyer where I want my text to be **Proper Cased**

- Proper Case: First Letter Capital and rest is small.

> e.g. *I Am A Member Of A Graphic Design Family*.

Please see the attached video for your reference.
[image: Video]

What I actually want is to convert the **UPPERCASE LETTERS** to **Proper Case Letter**

Comment: Search and replace?

Comment: What platform? Mac can do this in any text editor - but not Photoshop itself - after that, just copy/paste.

Comment: @Tetsujin theres no reason why you couldn't sript this or use any of the ready made advanced search and replace scripts. But yeah on winbdiows its not any different

Comment: @joojaa Search and replace won't work, I am having a list of different text on each line. And approximately I have more than 40 lines in my design.

Comment: @SumitYadav why would search and replace care about how many fields you have?

Comment: Copy Text - Paste into BBEdit - Change Case - Copy Text - Paste back into same layer in Photoshop [ It can't be done in Photoshop ]

Comment: FYI, this is sometimes referred to as "Title Case". Which is what BBEdit and InDesign call it.

Comment: & for sake of completeness, Apple calls it 'Capitalise' [which personally I think is a poor description] in the Transform sub-menu of many apps.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really an automatic option built in Photoshop.

As everyone said in the comments your best bet is to extract all the text to an external text editor (plenty of them can quickly convert to proper case with a shortcut) and paste it back with search and replace for each field.

There are add-ons for easily exporting all text from PSD, for example [this one](https://exchange.adobe.com/creativecloud.details.101045.export-all-text-for-psd.html).